# wpf flood fill image part

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want fill this image with color (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mi5al.png)

to get this result
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETXAp.png)

any help in this please and thank you guys for your help
just want implement flood fill in wpf window to fill part of image with color

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a [tour] and see [ask]. Note that StackOverflow is not a code writing service. You need to show some effort to solve the problem, and ask specific questions about your code.

Comment: Do you have to start off with a bitmap rather than vector?